# How to create a wrapper component that accepts a generic type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm trying to figure out how to define a wrapper component that accepts a generics declaration. Here's what I have:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { FlatListProps } from 'react-native';
import { GestureHandlerRootView, FlatList as RNGHFlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const FlatList = React.forwardRef<RNGHFlatList, FlatListProps<any>>((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView>
            <RNGHFlatList ref={ref} {...props} />
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
});

export default FlatList;
```

I try to avoid `any` at all times in my code, so how can I fix this up, so that this wrapper accepts a generic type?

```
const FlatList = React.forwardRef<RNGHFlatList, FlatListProps<T>>((props, ref) => {
//                                                           ^^^ Cannot find name 'T'
```

I have tried many variations, I even tried changing this wrapper to use the `function` keyword:

```
function FlatList<T>() {
    return React.forwardRef<RNGHFlatList, FlatListProps<T>>((props, ref) => {
        return (
            <GestureHandlerRootView>
                <RNGHFlatList ref={ref} {...props} />
            </GestureHandlerRootView>
        );
    });
}
```

This, however, creates a different error when I try to use the component:

```
return (
    <FlatList
//   ^^^^^^^^ Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<FlatListProps<unknown> & RefAttributes<FlatList>>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'
        ref={ref}
//      ^^^ Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
        inverted
        data={data}
//      . . .
);
```

How can I get this to work?